# Show Spinner as Action in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an ActionBar with custom view. In this custom view I have a spinner with custom adaptor to show Icon and text. Is there a way to show selected spinner item in ActionBar as icon only and hide text?

Comment: Just to clarify: is the desired behavior that when the spinner is not selected only the icon is shown and when the spinner is selected both icon and text are shown?

Comment: Yes, show Spinner as an icon in action bar and when user pressed it it will show both icon and text.